# immutableJs Actualizar key de objeto con segundo orden de Map

Tags: javascript, redux

Buenas tardes, estoy en un proyecto donde tengo que usar **Redux** para el estado de mi aplicación en **Meteor**, pero al manejar un reducer tipo objeto tuve que usar **ImmutableJs** donde al usar la propiedad *.set* para cambiar el valor de un key de este tipo:

```
const stateMenu = {
  menu0: {
    nombre: 'Adm de PBX',
    activo: false,
    abierto: false,
    habilitado: true,
    iconItem: "fa fa-server"
  },
 menu1: {
    nombre: 'Video Conferencia',
    activo: false,
    abierto: false,
    habilitado: true,
    iconItem: "fa fa-video-camera"
  },
}
```

El reducer tiene este estilo

```
export function menu(state = map(stateMenu), action) {
      switch (action.type) {
        ...
      }
    }
```

El retorno de un case del switch

```
return state.set('menu0.abierto', true);
```

no me funciona ni así

```
return state.menu0.set('abierto', true);
```

me podrian ayudar a ver como se cambie el valor de los objetos de segundo nivel del stateMenu con immutablejs

Gracias.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que te puede servir es `setIn`. El primer parámetro debe ser un array con los niveles de profundidad, el segundo parámetro, el nuevo valor.

```
state.setIn(['menu0', 'abierto'], true);
```

Comment: Gracias.! me funciono.! acabo de revisar la Doc y existe _Deep persistent changes_

Comment: De nada. Si te sirvió mi respuesta considera votar/marcarla como correcta. Saludos.

Comment: Si en lo que tenga 15 puntos de reputación te marco porque no me deja.!

Comment: Jaja lo olvidé ;) No te preocupes